# How 'Delete' works in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, memory

I'm little confused with js 'delete' operator.

for example

```
var data = { 
   list : [a, b, c]
}
var temp = data;

console.log(temp.list[2]); //Result 'c'
console.log(data.list[2]); //Result 'c'

delete temp.list[2];

console.log(temp.list[2]); //Result undefined
console.log(data.list[2]); //Result undefined why?
```

in this case, 
I have just only deleted `temp.list[2]` but `data.list[2]` shows undefined as well.

does 'delete' operator trace array address and delete data in it?
is that why `data.list[2]` is also undefined? (because `data.list[2]` has address, not the actual data itself)
I think there is explanation. can you help me?

Comment: nothing to do with delete ... this has to do with the fact that temp and data refer to the same array

Comment: See [Copying an array by value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript?rq=1) to see why `var temp=data;` does not make an independent copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reference type

```
var data = [] ==> instance
var temp = data; ==> data reference

get temp ==> return data

// shallow copy !!! 
var temp = Object.assign([], data); ===> instance



console.log(temp.list[2]); //Result undefined

console.log(data.list[2]); //Result c
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 2):

Check out all the great references others have posted.  But for a quick solution use the ES6 spread operator to create a copy.

```
    var data = { 
    list : ["a", "b", "c"]
    }
    var temp = {...data};  // this is now a copy not a reference
```

[More on the spread operator](https://davidwalsh.name/spread-operator)

in other words this isnt a delete issue, its a reference vs copy issue

Comment: This is the most ridiculous abuse of the spread operator ever ... have an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Complex types in JS are passed by reference, unless you explicitly take care of copying them.

What is happening here is:

```
var data = {        // <--\
   list : [a, b, c] // <----------------------------------------------
}                   // <--/                                           |
var temp = data;  // this is NOT a copy, but literally a pointer to -/
```

Try

```
var temp = Object.assign({}, data);
```

if you want a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Your question touches on several topics:

First, delete operator removes the given property from the object, but when used to remove an element from an array, the array length is not affected:

```
let trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
delete trees[3];
alert(trees.length); //shows 5
```

If this is not what you want, consider using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method instead. It is really powerful and can be used not only to remove elements.

```
let trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
trees.splice(3, 1);
alert(trees.length); //shows 4
```

Second, as everybody has already mentioned, `var temp = data;` doesn't create a copy of your object, it's just copies a reference. To make a fully identical shallow clone of your object, you could write:

```
let clone = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), 
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
```

This call makes a truly exact copy of obj, including all properties: enumerable and non-enumerable, data properties and setters/getters – everything, and with the right `[[Prototype]]`, when `Object.assign()` method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object